# References c# visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have been working on this project in *Visual Studio 2010* using ***C#*** a few days before *Windows 10* update and it worked fine but now when I try to run the program and it tells me the following :

> The type or name of the 'Drawing' namespace does not exist in the
>   'Tekla.Structures' namespace (missing an assembly reference?)

and the same for *Tekla.Structures.Model*, *Tekla.Structures.Model.Operations* ... as you can see in the following image:

[image: Errors in uses]

What I am doing is removing the references and adding them again and in this way the program recognizes it well, but if I clean the solution and try to generate the solution again, the problem arises again ...

What could be the problem?

Comment: How are you adding the references and where are the assemblies located that you are referencing?

Comment: Well, Tekla isn't going to be happy about it.  That's [where](https://support.tekla.com/?loggedIn=true) you need to find help.

Comment: @Erno I add the references with right click over references and adding new ones. And the assemblies are in my desktop!

Comment: Open the actual project file (.csproj) and see what is there for such references. With that you might find the cause (and the solution).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to use Tekla reference correctly.

I suggest that you can use NugetPackage.

First, right click->References->choose Manage Nuget packages.

Second, choose the Browse->input 'TeklaOpenAPI' in textbox and choose the first.

Third, click install.

Finally after it has been installed, you will see the following correct using code without warning.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first you remove tekla references, select and right click, then remove
[remove reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9Sqi.jpg)

after right click on References and add reference
[add references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni0CO.jpg)

after you need add dll corresponding the version you want execute
[select references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCbyo.jpg)

pay attention when building the app, it only runs in the version you chose the dlls.